# Python decode_header splits the original string

Tags: python, string, email, parsing, email-headers

Using Python 3, I'm trying to parse e-mails from an `mbox` file.

```
for message in mailbox.mbox('file'):
    sender = message['From']
    c = decode_header(sender)
```

The raw e-mail has this unique `From:` header

```
From: "=?UTF-8?Q?Mark_from_Site?=" <info@site.com>
```

Anyway, `c` is

```
[(b'"', None), (b'Mark from Site', 'utf-8'), (b'" <info@site.com>', None)]
```

In this case, the line is unexpectedly split following the quotation marks `"` in multiple elements.

Handling this may be cumbersome, because there may be an undefined number of elements (not always 3 like above) in the list, according to the number of `"`, and there may also be other causes for splitting.

When there is no string encoding (that is: when the header is pure `ascii`), there is no split and `c` is `"Mark from Site" <info@site.com>`.

Is there a way to avoid this splitting also for non-`ascii` encodings?

Or, otherwise, how to correctly parse this kind of headers?

Answer (score 1):

What about doing the simplest thing, ie. converting all parts to Unicode and then glueing them together:

```
from = ''.join(t[0].decode(t[1] if t[1] else 'UTF-8') for t in decode_header(sender))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the `email.header` module handle encoding for you by creating an instance of `email.header.Header` with your string and the charset it should be encoded in.

```
from email.header import Header

for message in mailbox.mbox('file'):
    sender = Header(message['From'], "utf-8")
    c = decode_header(sender)
```

Comment: This in fact doesn't split strings. But now, the encodings of the headers are considered as if they all were `utf-8`. If instead I use `Header(message['From'])`, all the messages are considered as `us-ascii`. Is there a way to let `Header` recognize the correct encoding by itself?

Answer (score 0):

```py
str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(encoded_string)))
```

Not too obvious, but this should decode and correctly rebuild the header and convert it to a string. I also found this somewhere here on StackOverflow.

Not sure if it's the most elegant way, but seems to work for me.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.header.html for the documentation of these functions.